# redirecting to a url from a pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, redirect, routes

I have a number of PDFs in a rails application which have been converted into single page applications and I would now like to redirect the URL from:

`www.domain.com/public-pdf-path.pdf`

to

`www.domain.com/reports/new-non-pdf-url`

I've tried redirecting in the routes.rb file like such:

`get '/pdf-public-file-path.pdf', to: redirect('/reports/new-url-address')`

but it does not hit this redirect. Thoughts on how I could redirect a user to a new URL from the public file path where the pdf lives?

Comment: try it using htaccess

Comment: Are you running your app in the development environment?

Comment: I have tried in both dev, staging (heroku), and production (heroku) with no difference in behavior. In development, it appears the server never logs any type of information when visiting the /pdf-path.pdf Is this because it is relative to the application? If so, how\where can I capture this processes and change behavior?

Comment: @LowellMower you can try setting `config.serve_static_assets = false` in your environment config file. This will let you redirect even if file with such name is in the `/public` directory. However you won't be able to access any files from the `/public` at all.

Comment: @FixerRB I thought about that but it is not ideal as I still have our 404, 422, 504, etc. files there... but I suppose I could make those views and put a controller to handle them

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^DOMAINNAME\.pdf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://DOMAIN.com/newpath [R=301,L]
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact issue.  For me, moving/renaming/deleting the PDF I was trying to redirect made it work.  I used the same kind of call in routes.rb as the OP.